# Can we run javascript in sqlcl directly from command line, or do we need an sql wrapper script?

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I know that I can run an sql file directly from the command line as follows:

> /sql -LOGON user/password@tnsname ./scripts/sql_script.sql parameter1

And I know that I can call a javascript program from within the sqlcl shell as follows:

> /sql>script scripts/js_script.js &1

The question is do I have to use the sql-wrapper script, or how can I run the javascript directly from the command line without the wrapper as follows:

> /sql -LOGON user/password@tnsname ./scripts/js_script.js parameter1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How have I not made that possible yet??  It's now on my todo list..

In the meantime you could do something like this.

```
➜  examples echo "script lsEngines.js" | sql klrice/klrice


SQLcl: Release 21.3 Production on Tue Jul 20 13:33:26 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Jul 20 2021 13:33:28 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

login.sql found in the CWD. DB access is restricted for login.sql.
Adjust the SQLPATH to include the path to enable full functionality.

ScriptEngineFactory Info
jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory@373f7450
    Script Engine: Oracle Nashorn (14.0.2)
    Engine Alias: nashorn
    Engine Alias: Nashorn
    Engine Alias: js
    Engine Alias: JS
    Engine Alias: JavaScript
    Engine Alias: javascript
    Engine Alias: ECMAScript
    Engine Alias: ecmascript
    Language: ECMAScript (ECMA - 262 Edition 5.1)
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

Where my "lsEngines.js" is this content

```
var ScriptEngineManager = Java.type("javax.script.ScriptEngineManager")
mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
var factories = mgr.getEngineFactories();

factories.forEach(function(factory) {

          ctx.write("ScriptEngineFactory Info\n" + factory.toString() + "\n");

          var engName = factory.getEngineName();
          var engVersion = factory.getEngineVersion();
          var langName = factory.getLanguageName();
          var langVersion = factory.getLanguageVersion();

          ctx.write("\tScript Engine: "+engName+" ("+engVersion+")\n");

          var engNames = factory.getNames();
          engNames.forEach(function(name) {
              ctx.write("\tEngine Alias: "+ name + "\n");
          })

          ctx.write("\tLanguage: "+langName+" ("+langVersion+")\n");

      })
```